# Program stops when i input any character

Tags: c

*the code is from a book named 
Programming  with c by Byron gottfried *

*when i try to input a character, the program stops *

```
int main()
{

    char line[80];
    int count;
    printf(" Enter a line of text below:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n], &line");

    for(count=0;line[count]!='\0';++count){

        if(((line[count]>='0') && (line[count] < '9'))||
            ((line[count] >= 'A') && (line[count]< 'Z'))||
            ((line[count]>= 'a' ) && (line[count] <'z' )))
             putchar(line[count]+1);
             else if(line[count] =='9' ) putchar('0');
             else if(line[count] == 'Z')putchar('A');
             else if(line[count] == 'z')putchar('a');
             else putchar('.');

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tell us the problem, we'll figure out its reason.

Comment: The `scanf` looks so suspicious it really is no longer funny. This question is so... goofy it almost deserves an upvote. If not a typo. No offense! :-)

Comment: I think I see what this is trying to do, and several different reasons why it might not be working for you, but I cannot disentangle the (deliberately?) obtuse way of going about it, the possible bugs, and the definite bugs enough to give any explanation that would make sense at your level of understanding.  Possibly what you need is to throw away this textbook and get a better one.

Comment: When i input a character the program stops

Comment: @GirishGogia : You need to edit the question to clarify it, not add clarification in comments (that may not be read).

Comment: I have just checked the 2nd edition of that book, and that code does not appear anywhere, and certainly not that error.  What edition?  What page?

Comment: Pg-139,and the code does compile

Comment: Yes, it compiles. But is very wrong. as mentioned in the answer, the `scanf()` is coded incorrectly. You shouldn't ignore warnings. I took your code and did as Clifford recommended and it appears to work properly.

Comment: @GirishGogia : OK found it on P139 - the PDF I was searching is a scan with inaccurate OCR, however the code is correct; you have simply transcribed it incorrectly. It compiles because it is syntactically valid; it is however semantic nonsense.  Many compilers would issue a warning for this error given suitablly high warning settings

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
scanf("%[^\n], &line");
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", line);
```

i.e. Put the closing `"` in the format string in the correct place, and no `&` before `line`.

Moreover, on some platforms the stdout buffer is not flushed until it contains a newline or becomes full, so you should add a `fflush( stdout)` call.  You will get away with it on Windows.

You might also consider simplifying the code by using the `ctype.h` functions.

---

Since this is a simple transcription error (the book referenced does not contain this error) rather than a programming question, and the question has been closed, this purely an aside, but I'd suggest the following implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char line[80];
    int count;

    /* read in the entire string */
    printf("Enter a line of text below:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", line);

    /* encode each individual character and display it */
    for (count = 0; line[count] != '\0'; ++count)
    {
        char plaintext = line[count];
        char encoded = '.';

        if (isupper(plaintext))
        { 
            encoded = (((plaintext + 1) - 'A') % 26) + 'A';
        }
        else if (islower(plaintext))
        {
            encoded = (((plaintext + 1) - 'a') % 26) + 'a';
        }
        else if (isdigit(plaintext))
        {
            encoded = (((plaintext + 1) - '0') % 10) + '0';
        }

        putchar(encoded);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did that, same problem

Comment: Likely, `scanf("%[^\n]", line);` was meant.

Comment: @FUZxxl : fixed - I did not notice that - I've not seen anyone make that error before!

Comment: The problem must have been with the quotation marks

Comment: @GirishGogia : ... and the ampersand. You make it sound as if there is some doubt about the cause of the problem.  There is no doubt - the scanf call was nonsense.